# Why not import A.B in Python?

Tags: python

This is a language design question. Why the designer didn't use

```
import A.B
```

instead of

```
from A import B
```

assuming A is a module that contains function B. Isn't it better to have a single style for import syntax? What was the design principle behind this? I think that the Java style import syntax feels more natural.

Comment: You can't `import A.B` if `B` is a function - it has to be a module.

Comment: Yes. I'm asking why the designed that way.

Comment: You can import like that

Comment: You probably think Java syntax is more natural because you're more accustomed to Java... @mishik nobody is saying you can't. He's asking why there are two.

Comment: So why I'm getting error for import multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool?

Comment: @mishik you actually cannot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python import statements primarily exist to load modules and packages. You have to import a module before you can use it. The second form of import is merely an additional feature, loading the module and then copying some parts of it into the local namespace.

Java import statements exist to make shortcuts to names loaded in other modules. Java import statements don't load anything, but merely move things into the local namespace. In Java you don't need to import modules in order to use them. The import statement has nothing to do with whether or not a module is loaded.

So the two languages take quite a different approach to importing. The imports statements are basically just not doing the same thing. Python's imports are for loading and Java imports are for shortcuts.

Java's approach would be somewhat problematic in python. In Java it's pretty easy to sort of what's a class/module/package from the syntax. Python does not have that advantage. As a result, the compiler and the reader would have difficulty determing what is and isn't meant to be a reference to an external package. For that reason, Python's designer chose to make it explicit and force you to specify which external module you want to load.

Comment: What don't we need to *load* modules in Java and do need to load them in  Python?

Comment: In other words, what are the differences between Java and Python modules?

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi, see my last paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

Consistency. `import A.B` *never* adds `B` to the local namespace, even for cases in which it is valid; it simply makes `B` available via `A`, which functions already naturally are.

Comment: Let says A and B are modules and C is a function with this hierarchy: A.B.C and assume I just import A. Why shouldn't I be able to access A.B.C?

Comment: Submodules are not imported automatically. You would need to import `A.B` to get to `A.B.C`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with modules, but not functions, eg.

`os.path` is commonly imported like that

Comment: `os.path` is a module, though. You can't do it with, say, `sys.stdin`.

Comment: `os.path` is a special case, and should not be used as an example in this sort of situation.